# Unable to do multi-table item create in Entity-Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a working ASP.NET Web API that I am trying to convert to ASP.NET Core.  I am struggling with a multi-table item add.  I have the following 4 tables (SQL Server):

Template,
TemplateAction - with a foreign key to Template,
TemplateGroup - with a foreign key to Template,
TemplateCell - with a foreign key to Template, a foreign key to TemplateAction  and a foreign key to TemplateGroup.

[image]

The code to add the "Template" (with one TemplateAction, one TemplateGroup and one TemplateCell) is as follows:

```
  public async Task<int> CreateTemplate(string userId, TemplateCreateDTO dto)
{
    using (var context = MyDataContext.Instance) // Injected in ASP.NET Core (no using)
    {
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

        // Create s single default Group
        var groups = new[]
        {
            new TemplateGroup
            {
                Name = "Row Name",
                Description = string.Empty,
                SortOrder = 0
            }
        };

        // Create s single default Action
        var actions = new[]
        {
            new TemplateAction
            {
                Name = "Column Name",
                Description = string.Empty,
                SortOrder = 0
            }
        };

        // All cells are enabled when a Template is created
        var cells = new[]
        {
            new TemplateCell
            {
                TemplateGroupId = groups[0].Id,
                TemplateActionId = actions[0].Id,
                IsEnabled = true
            }
        };

        var template = new Template
        {
            Name = dto.Name,
            Description = dto.Description,
            InitialRisk = dto.InitialRisk,
            CreatedWhen = now,
            CreatedByUserId = userId,
            ModifiedWhen = now,
            ModifiedByUserId = userId,
            TemplateGroups = groups,
            TemplateActions = actions,
            TemplateCells = cells
        };

        context.Templates
            .Add(template);

        await context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return template.Id;
    }
}
```

The same code in ASP.NET Core 3.1 (EF Core 3.1) - apart from the context is injected - fails with the following error:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_TemplateCell_TemplateAction\". The conflict occurred in database \"MyDB\", table \"dbo.TemplateAction\", column 'Id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.
```

I have tried numerous things, but have been unable to add the template.  Can anyone see what the issue may be?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var cells = new[]
        {
            new TemplateCell
            {
                TemplateGroupId = groups[0].Id,
                TemplateActionId = actions[0].Id,
                IsEnabled = true
            }
        };
```

the ids will have no value when you try to save..

I guess you have to do something like this

```
var cells = new[]
        {
            new TemplateCell
            {
                TemplateGroup = groups[0],
                TemplateAction = actions[0],
                IsEnabled = true
            }
        };
```

when the referenced object is saved it will set the fk to you..

anyway, you see that to ensure that your group / action / cell point to same template you should use a composite primary key if you realy want that all have a fk to the template, right?

or is expected that they can reference different templates?

Comment: A Template / Actions / Groups / Cells in a single disjoint thing (no cross template references).  So no many to many.  The database is as it was before moving to core.

Comment: That fixed it.  Marked as answer.  I could not see the first for the trees.  Thank you.